# Can't Embed YouTube Link Within Django Template Tag, Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: django, youtube, django-templates, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently attempting to embed a user-submitted YouTube link via a Django form within a Twitter Bootstrap layout.

The space for the video is appearing and the source code reflects the correct information and link, but neither the video nor the player appears. I'm also using the "flex-video" class from this link for a responsive layout http://poslavsky.com/blog/2012/04/01/responsive-video-in-twitter-bootstrap/ but it doesn't work when that class is changed to another name such as "video" either.

This is the code:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span12">
    <span>{{story.author}}</span><br>

    <span>{{story.zip_code}}</span><br>

    <span>{{story.date}}</span><br>

    <p>{{story.copy}}</p>
    <div class="image">
        {% if story.pic %}
        <img src="{{ story.pic.url }}" alt="some_image_alt_text" />
        {%  endif %}
    </div>
    <div class="flex-video">
            {% if story.video %}
            <p> <iframe width="460" height="250" src="{{ story.video}}" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
                </p>
        {% endif %}
        </div>
</div>
```

Any insight greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it's a valid YouTube URL? Copy the content of the `src` attribute on the rendered page, and view it in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `{{story.video}}` gives Youtube video Url something similar to this `http://youtube.com/watch?v=ASO_ypdnsQ` which is direct youtube url, and not embed url.

Embed URL for same video is different than direct url, like this `http://youtube.com/embed/....`

I created a custom template tag, here is how.

```
import urlparse
...

@register.inclusion_tag('video_embed.html', takes_context=True)
def youtube_embed(context, url):
    url_data = urlparse.urlparse(url)
    query = urlparse.parse_qs(url_data.query)
    video_id = query["v"][0]
    context['embed_url'] = ('http://youtube.com/embed/%s' % video_id)
    return context
```

Then, in templates just load the tag, and pass the youtube url. It will give embed url from normal url.